# What could cause mysql db read to return stale data

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, mysql2

I am chasing a problem on a mysql application. At some point my client INSERTs some data, using a query wrapped in a `START TRANSACTION; .... COMMIT;` statement. Right after that another client comes are read back the data, and it is not there (I am sure of the order of things).

I am running nodejs, express, mysql2, and use connection pooling, with multiple statements queries.

What is interesting is that I see weird things on mysqlworkbench. I just had a workbench instance which would not see the newly inserted data either. I opened a second one, it saw the new data. Minutes later, the first instance would still not see the new data. Hit 'Reconnect to DBMS', and now it sees it. The workbench behaviour, if applied to my node client, would explain the bad result I see in node / mysql2.

There is some sort of caching going on somewhere... no idea where to start :-( Any pointers? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your clients are living in their own snapshot of the database, which would be true if they have an open transaction using the REPEATABLE-READ isolation level. In other words, no data committed after that client started its transaction will be visible to that client.

One workaround is to force a new transaction to start. Just run COMMIT in the client session where it appears to be viewing stale data. That will resolve any open transaction and the next query will start a new transaction.

Another way you can test is to use a [locking read query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) such as `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`. This will read the most recently committed data, regardless of the client's transaction isolation level. That is, even if the client had started their transaction using REPEATABLE-READ, a locking read behaves as if they had started their transaction with READ-COMMITTED.

Comment: Sure enough, the COMMIT commands makes the new data visible. These problems started coming up when I recently moved to pooled connections, to improve performance. I guess this is not a transparent change after all and requires some attention! 
When you say "In other words, no data committed after that client started its transaction", do you refer to a simple query, or a query starting with a `START TRANSACTION` statement?

Comment: I suggest you read about repeatable-read snapshots: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html